# CMYK and RGB transparency

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I mainly studied Illustrator to use it in T-Shirt custom design.

Now, I have this problem.  According to the tutorials that I see.  When working on print jobs, I should use
CMYK mode rather than RGB.

I am just having trouble utilizing blending mode in CMYK transparency panel.  They sometimes dont look so well
especially doing abstract designs.

If I switch to RGB, the design looks good in illustrator but does'nt print well on my CMYK printer.

Question is, how do I do about this problem of mine.  Anyone having this?

Comment: The thing is unless you know the production system well and are capable of doing a hard proof then working with cmy does not fix any gamut problem. So working in cmy is only usrfull if you know well the production system and have profiles and calibrated systems for proofing and know the limirations of your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your t shirt is being produced you may be able to stick to RGB. If your t shirt is being screen printed you are only limited by the printing press of the company you are using. A professional printing company will be able to produce any Pantone color for you. When you color separate your artwork providing you have less individual colors than your printing companies machines have color stations your artwork is fine as it is. If you have more colors than they are capable of printing then you will need to either find a company with bigger machinery or switch to CYMK.